# React checkbox check, but doesn't uncheck

Tags: react-native

I'm creating app in React Native and I need checkbox there. I can check a checkbox, but I cannot uncheck it.

I'm using *state* to know, if it's checked/unchecked.

```
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native';
this.state = {
  checked: false,
}

<CheckBox value={this.state.checked} onValueChange={() => this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked })} />
```

I was expecting, that `this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked })}` will negate `this.state.checked` but it's doesn't seems like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working for me.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, CheckBox } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      checked: false
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <CheckBox
          value={this.state.checked}
          onValueChange={() => this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked })}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! I don't understand why your code works and mine not, but OK. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know from where are you imported that checkbox, but for example: https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/checkbox.html 
This needs a prop `checked`, but not a prop `value` 
In your case:

```
<CheckBox checked={this.state.checked} onValueChange={() => this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked })} />
```

Comment: In this case your code should work. Can You check if some other element isnt collapsed over?